# Symfony 5 - best practices to handle query exception

Tags: php, symfony, exception, handle

i want to ask more experienced symfony dev about exception handling.
I know i should make and EventListener and inside handle exceptions.

But what if i got isnert into exception value should not be null?

```
public function onKernelException(ExceptionEvent $event)
{
    $exception = $event->getThrowable();
    $message = sprintf(
        'ERROR:%s|CODE:%s',
        $exception->getMessage(),
        $exception->getCode()
    );

    $response = new Response();
    $response->setContent($message);

    if ($exception instanceof \PDOException) {
        $response->setStatusCode($exception->getStatusCode());
        $response->headers->replace($exception->getHeaders());
    } else {
        $response->setStatusCode(Response::HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }

    $event->setResponse($response);
}

    App\EventListener\RuneBonusInsertExceptionListener:
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.exception }
```

is that right or should i do this in other way?

The second idea i got is handle this in action controller something like:

```
    public function addNewBonus(Request $request, RuneBonusRegisterer $registerer)
    {
        $bonusData = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);

        $form = $this->createForm(RuneBonusType::class);
        $form->submit($bonusData);

        if (!$form->isValid()) {
            return $this->json([
                'errors' => $form->getErrors(true, false)
            ], 200);

        }

        $bonus = $form->getData();
        $registerer->register($bonus);

        return $this->json(
            $bonus, 200
        );
    }
```

Comment: the short error is, you shouldn't allow that object to be inserted in the first place. if the user has to provide that value, you have to make sure it's there. the form validator can only do so much on it's own, sometimes you have to add something. Since you omit all the complete error message AND the RuneBonusType AND the RuneBonus entity AND the RuneBonusRegisterer, it's quite unclear, where it should be best placed, but it's definitely a code smell / error to let that object be inserted into the database unchecked, since it's a preventable error. form validation is key but only part.

Comment: catching exceptions to provide an error message via event listener is a good measure to catch unforeseen errors, but "value should not be null" isn't one of them.

Comment: Okay so i added Assert to my entity and i did this: https://pastebin.com/nfsG1ZJE
is it okay?

Comment: status code of 200 sounds odd, 400 is probably more appropriate?, and I suppose it's advisable to wrap the error messages in a meaningful json structure. just to be able to distinguish between different outcomes.

Comment: yea, status wasnt good, you're right, i got json structure - array
[
    "ERROR: Item name should not be blank\n",
    "ERROR: Box price should not be blank\n"
]